# Missing System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting assembly reference

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Noob question guys: I'm trying to understand WPF technology, and specifically I will have a project that needs charts. I have added the reference 
[image]

In the XAML i was advised to add: (taken from here : https://mitchelsellers.com/blogs/2011/04/20/wpf-chart-styling-explained)

```
xmlns:datavis="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
    xmlns:charting="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
```

However when it then try add a Chart in the XAML it gives the following error.

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error       The name "chart" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit". 
>   Error       The type 'charting:chart' was not found. Verify that you are not missing an assembly reference and that all referenced assemblies have been built
>   Error       The tag 'chart' does not exist in XML namespace 'clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit'.

What am I missing/not understanding?

The XAML gives the following error.
[image]

But when i look at the Toolkit in the object browser, i see the charting/chart

[image]

Comment: Try cleaning and rebuilding your project...

Comment: Ok - thanks, after clean of solution - still errors, but slightly different...  
Error  The name "chart" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit". CustomValueConverterDemo

Comment: Letter C in word "chart" should be in upper case.

Comment: Ouch - good spot, my bad - thanks for looking.

Answer (score 3):

I have found working with the various toolkits from yesteryear to be a bit frustrating.  NuGet is typically my savior, offering libraries directly without installing anything outside of my IDE.

A note for future posts to is to provide the actual trouble code, like the MainWindow.xaml.

I created a working example [here](https://github.com/mikeruhl/SOChart).

As noted above, I try to use NuGet now for these things.  The object you're looking for is in `System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit`.  The namespaces you're looking for can now be referenced here:

1. xmlns:chartingToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Charting;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"
2. xmlns:visualizationToolkit="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization;assembly=System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit"

Once those are added, you can add your chart:

`<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="chtSummary" Width="770" Height="400" Title="My Chart Title">
...
</chartingToolkit:Chart>`

Again, see the [github repo](https://github.com/mikeruhl/SOChart) for a working example.  Good luck!